# Only show logging info in dev-mode in NodeJS/Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I have a javascript class which can be used in both the browser and NodeJS.

Suppose the class looks like this

```
class BarFoo {
    lookup() {
         // Do magic
         if (magicFailed && window.DEVELOP) {
             console.log('Show some info to help debugging...');
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

To make this example also work for NodeJS I can imaging that the `global` 
In this example I only show the log message if the app is in developing mode (`window.DEVELOP === true`). But I would like to use this class also in a nodeJS app, so I don't have a `window` object. What is the preferred way to set this up for both?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

Start your app with:

```
NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

Then check it like so:

```
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
const isDev = isServer ? process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' : window.DEVELOP

if (isDev) {
  // ...
}
```